# Error: Manifest version 2 is deprecated, and support will be removed in 2023 - Bypass Paywalls Clean 3.1.7.7

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, error-correction

I'd like to know if there is a way to overcome the following error of the google chrome extension "Bypass Paywalls Chrome Clean" and it doesn't work as before:

[image]

I tried to install the last version and I tried also the similar extension "bypass-paywalls-chrome", but I got the same error.

Comment: Support hasn't been removed, you can ignore the notification for the time being.

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, thank you for your comment. I found this error because the extension stopped to work. In the past I removed and installed it again and the things go on their way, but now it stops to work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: That's just a depreciation notice. There are 100 different reasons that could cause this and it's definitely not the one you went for. But to find the real culprit you'd need to list a lot more details, starting with classic clarification of useless "it doesn't work" statement. Then you could also list other extensions you're using, whether it works if you enable just it and no other extensions, if there are any errors in the console, etc.

Comment: Hello @Destroy666 I tried to disable the other extensions and the result is the same (doesn't work means that I cannot see this webpage: https://24plus.ilsole24ore.com/art/culle-vuote-ecco-province-italiane-controtendenza-AEn1YqSD?s=hpf). In the console there is only the error I showed you.

Comment: Cannot see as in what happens exactly? Blank page, error? In that case Network tab should be also checked for any responses with errors (usually but not always marked in red color).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [older](https://gitlab.com/magnolia1234/bypass-paywalls-chrome-clean/-/releases) versions of the extension. Also, I'm not sure where you got the extension from, because the latest version seems to be v3.1.7.3 (official release), not v3.1.7.7, as you have posted in the title. If you got it from an unofficial site, I'd be concerned about getting a virus.

Talking about viruses in a Chrome extension, you can use [crxcavator.io](https://crxcavator.io/) site to scan if an extension has a virus or if it is risky. The extension must still be in the Chrome Webstore for the site to be able to scan it.

As an alternative, you can use [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/) to scan an extension that you have downloaded on your PC as .crx/.zip format.

In the future, you can use [crx4chrome.com](https://www.crx4chrome.com/) to download older versions of an extension. The most popular extensions can be found there.

As an alternative, you could try using an older version of Chromium that fully supports the extension. [This](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/) site is for Chromium for Windows. Also, if I recall correctly, Brave, and Vivaldi will still offer support for Manifest Version 2, even after MV2 support will be stopped for Chrome/Firefox.

Another alternative is to use [Bypass Paywalls](https://github.com/iamadamdev/bypass-paywalls-chrome) Chrome extensions.

For some more simple Chrome extensions, if you know a bit of programming related to web design or just programming in general, you could be able to figure out how to turn that extension into a Tampermonkey script/ script that can be used in Chrome developer tools/ bookmarklet, where MV2 isn't affecting the script anymore. Just make sure to not spread that script online. Or if you want to spread it online, ask for the Chrome extension creator's permission and also offer credit to him/her in the script.

Since we're talking about the transition from Manifest Version 2 to Manifest Version 3, I found [this](https://docs.plasmo.com/itero/mv2-to-mv3) site that allegedly is able to automatically aid one to convert an extension from MV2 to MV3 using their converter called Itero MV2-MV3 Converter. I think once MV2 will be stopped getting supported on Chrome/Firefox, more converters like this will pop up.

Almost forgot, some paywalls don't work while in Incognito mode on a browser, so you won't even need a Chrome extension for bypassing paywalls. I know it works like this for [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/).

**Edit:**

[This](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/extension-manifest-converter) tool (made by someone who works on Chrome's extensions team) converts the manifest file from version 2 to version 3, but I don't know to what degree. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/extension-manifest-converter/) it's described how it's done.

Comment: Hello @rd51 thank you very much for the precious explanation. I tried the extension you mentioned, but I get the same error and it doesn't allow me to view webpages that before I was able to see.